# Subtracting an open path shape from a shape

Tags: sketch-app

I'm making an letter icon using two shapes, one above the other. The below shape is the letter and the above shape is the letter fold.

I want to subtract the letter fold which is a path from the letter shape. Each time I've tried I've not had any luck with it ended up showing a triangle shape cut out.

Any help here very much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to expand the path first (Layer -> Convert to Outlines) and then it will behave as expected.

Answer (score 1):

As Westside suggested, you first need to convert your stroke to path then you can use pathfinder to get your result.

1). Select your stroke > Go to > **Object > Expand** and hit OK (make sure stroke is selected)

2). Now shift Select the below object and use pathfinder to subtract.

--This Video can help--
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rQZXS1AhxVg